# How to call secrets from AWS secrets manager into a CloudFormation Template

Tags: json, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Hoping someone can help. Trying to call a secret stored in AWS secrets manager into my CF Template but can't seem to find the correct way.

Basically I want my stored secrets to be populated in the fields below.

```
  AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
    S3AccessCreds:
      type: S3
      accessKeyId:     <-----#secret to be populated here
      secretKey:       <-----#secret to be populated here
      buckets: XYZ
```

So far I have got to this...

```
AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication:
    S3AccessCreds:
      type: S3
      accessKeyId: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:my-secrets-name}}'
      secretKey: '{{resolve:secretsmanager:my-secrets-name}}'
      buckets: XYZ
```

The error in the logs I get is the following

cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Failed to retrieve https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/MybucketName/oracle/01_post-setup.sh: HTTP Error 403 : ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?
`InvalidAccessKeyId`The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.{{resolve:secretsmanager:}}

But it doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Cheers

Comment: "But it doesn't work." is not specific. What exactly is happening. Any errors?

Comment: Do you need to indicate the actual value e.g. `{{resolve:secretsmanager:my-secrets-name:SecretString:my-access-key}}`?

Comment: Jarmod, but surely I wouldnt specify the actual value of the secret would I? i am trying to keep the value out of the template all together? maybe I didnt understand what you mean?

Comment: Does the secret contain a single encrypted string, or a JSON object with multiple fields?

Comment: And, of course, has the secret been populated at the time the script is run? The error message appears to be caused by CloudFormation not getting anything back from the secret.

Comment: yes the secret is a single string and present at the time of the script being run

Comment: Is `{{resolve:secretsmanager:}}` a literal part of the error message, or have you redacted it?

Comment: this is what i get 

cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Failed to retrieve https://s3-eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/<bucketName>/oracle/01_post-setup.sh: HTTP Error 403 : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code><Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>{{resolve:secretsmanager:<my-secret-name>}}

Comment: You seem to be referencing the secret correctly, _but_ you're using it in a `Metadata` block, not a `Properties` block for a resource. I wonder if dynamic resolution isn't allowed there? I checked the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/dynamic-references.html#dynamic-references-considerations), and they don't say that it's not supported in that situation, but do say that it's not supported for transforms or custom resources. Maybe just an omission on their part?

Comment: The only other advice that I can give is to try out the secret reference in a dummy resource, to ensure that you're using the correct syntax (it looks correct, but there's always a possibility that I'm misreading something). I recommend setting a `Tag` value to the access key secret contents (which is not an actual secret, so exposing it for testing should not be an issue). If it works in a resource but not in your metadata, then you know the answer. If it doesn't work in the resource, then you can look more closely at the reference to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting you specify the actual values. I'm suggesting you specify the key of the actual secret. BTW you need to prefix user handles with the @ sign in comments otherwise users don't get notified.